# Run native code when triggering alarms with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have an example that implements an example of Android Alarm Manager with flutter, the event is called normal, however, I want that when the alarm goes off, a native code (Java or Kt) is executed.
Example:
As soon as the alarm goes off even in the background or locked screen, the app will execute my code in Java.

In native Java we created a class that inherits from BroadcastReceiver and implements the onReceive method, in Android Native I would open my app even in the background with native code.

How can I get the flutter to call my native code to run when the alarm is triggered?

My code example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';
import 'package:android_intent/android_intent.dart';
import 'package:android_intent/flag.dart';
import 'package:platform/platform.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Alarme app',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Alarme'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

void _openLinkInGoogleChrome() {
  print('entered');
  if (const LocalPlatform().isAndroid) {
  // **run Native code java here that implemented onReceive on class .java or .kt !!!**
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void adicionarAlarme(BuildContext context) async {
    await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
        const Duration(seconds: 3), 0, _openLinkInGoogleChrome);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Clique no botão abaixo para adicionar um alarme',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => adicionarAlarme(context),
        tooltip: 'Adicionar alarme',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: MethodChannels are what you're looking for

Comment: This link reference right: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels ?

Comment: This method works... But i need pass a parameter BuildContext to my kotlin class to request permission and the context is not possible to send when using invokeMethod because her only support are primitive types. But, thanks.

Comment: For request permission on kotlin is need Context object